# Oral allergy syndrom, continuation of continuous consumption of allergen

Tags: allergies

Wikipedia states on [its page](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Oral_allergy_syndrome) that

> In addition, patients are advised to avoid the triggering foods, particularly nuts.

And same thing goes for [webmd.com](http://www.webmd.com/allergies/features/oral-allergy-syndrome-foods?page=2)

> The basic rule: If a food makes you uncomfortable, don’t eat it.

So two very related questions flow from this:

1. Does continuous consumption cause such an allergic reaction to become stronger?
2. And if that is the case, by what mechanisms does that happen?

Comment: And if possible at all, I would greatly appreciate it if you could keep the explanation to like a first year bachelor level (as in, anything a first year bachelor student would be capable of comprehending, not necessarily things that a first year bachelor student is typically taught) O:) . Anything beyond that I am likely to not understand even if I do take my time. And this is my first question on biology.SE so I hope I did everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When you ingest an allergen for the first time, your body produces many of an antibody called IgE with specificity toward that allergen. These IgE antibodies bind to mast cells, and basophils. When you encounter more allergen, they bind to these IgE on the surface of the mast cells and basophils, causing them to release a host of chemicals like histamine. Massive amount of histamine are the cause of anaphylaxis, so when more allergen interacts with more and more IgE, the situation worsens. The following figure is a detailed mechanism,

[image]

[Source](http://what-when-how.com/acp-medicine/allergic-response-part-1/)

We can also see, though, that histamine released is a function of total allergen, and eventually reaches a maximum regardless of allergen present,

[image]

[Source](http://openi.nlm.nih.gov/detailedresult.php?img=3199832_CTO-07-04-g-004&req=4)
Here they're showing histamine release vs allergen concentration while investigating allergic rhinitis.